# InvalidInputException (status: 400): Partition index not supported for the given partition key type

Tags: amazon-s3, indexing, aws-glue, amazon-athena, partitioning

I am trying to create an index on a partitioned column in AWS Glue for Athena.  I keep getting an error:

```
Unable to complete request to create index.
InvalidInputException (status: 400): Partition index not supported for the given partition key type.
```

The column type is varchar(50).  I tried changing it to string, but I continued to receive the same error message.  I added a parameter: {partition_filtering.enabled:true}.

What am I doing wrong? Am I missing a table property?

I tried changing column data types, and adding properties to the table.

Answer (score 0):

The column partition value was a boolean.  This prevented us from creating the index, even on a value that was not boolean.